# Low audio quality with Microsoft Translator

Tags: audio, xna, wav, microsoft-translator

I'm working on a desktop application built with XNA. It has a Text-To-Speech application and I'm using Microsoft Translator V2 api to do the job. More specifically, I'm using is the Speak method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512420.aspx), and I play the audio with SoundEffect and SoundEffectInstance classes.

The service works fine, but I'm having some issues with the audio. The quality is not very good and the volume is not loud enough.

I need a way to improve the volume programmatically (I've already tried some basic solutions in CodeProject, but the algorithms are not very good and the resulting audio is very low quality), or maybe use another api.

Are there some good algorithms to improve the audio programmatically? Are there other good text-to-speech api's out there with better audio quality and wav support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing off-line processing of audio, you can try using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net). It has very good tools for off-line processing of audio. If you are processing real-time streaming audio you can try using [SoliCall Pro](http://www.solicall.com/products.html#AddOnPro). It creates virtual audio device and filters all audio that it captures.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I tried Audacity and it works great, but I need a solution that I can embed on my application. SoliCall seems to work too, but I don't want to force the users to install third party software.

Comment: Take a look at http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=9456 - I think it shows how to use APIs with Audacity.